# histrory.push is not working when I am trying to redirect to other page after submiting the Form in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, web-deployment

*fromComponent.js*

```
 const history = useHistory();
 const handleUserSubmitData = () => {
    history.push("/");
  };

<Form onSubmit={() => handleUserSubmitData}>
<InputGroup hasValidation={firstName ? false : true}>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  required
                  onChange={handleFirstName}
                  placeholder="First Name"
                  isInvalid={firstNameError ? true : false}
                />
                {firstNameError && (
                  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                    {firstNameError}
                  </Form.Control.Feedback>
                )}
              </InputGroup>
<Button
                disabled={isSubmitDataEntered || !ispasswordMatched}
                variant="light"
                type="submit"
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
  </Form>
```

After submitting it is redirected to /? not to /. could you please help me out to solve this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the ***handleUserSubmitData*** function

Update the line as follow

```
...
<Form onSubmit={() => handleUserSubmitData()}> // call function here by adding parentheses //()
...
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for responding, after adding the parentheses I removed the arrow function then it got working. like this  onSubmit={handleUserSubmitData()}

Comment: @Thirumalesu Using `onSubmit={handleUserSubmitData()}` would just immediately invoke the callback. Use either `onSubmit={() => handleUserSubmitData()}` or `onSubmit={handleUserSubmitData}`.

Comment: @DrewReese when I am using any one which you mentioned, the react-bootstrap form is redirecting to /?.. not to / as now I am not sure why.

Comment: @Thirumalesu Then why did you accept an answer with code that *doesn't* work for you? I'm not saying this answer is wrong, it's clearly correct. I think you might have something else going on with your code that isn't shown to us, like where a queryString is added to the URL. Your code had what I'd consider to be a typo and should be closed as "not reproducible or caused by typo", and once corrected you are saying the code *still* doesn't work as expected. Can you edit your post with a complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese there is no query string it is just the home route URL. And even there is no code except submit button in the <Form></Form> component. okay, I will update the post with the complete code. but as of now when I use this is working fine onSubmit={handleUserSubmitData()}

Comment: @Thirumalesu handleUserSubmitData(), this will call the function even though you don't call it. You can write handleUserSubmitData  in stead. Like onSubmit={ handleUserSubmitData}

Comment: @Thirumalesu In the image you highlight the URL, `"/?"`, the `"?"` is the start of the queryString part of the URL... what is setting that? See [mcve].